# Crystal Report migration issue from 2008 to 2010 in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, version

I have converted my project from VS 2008 to VS2010 (3.5 to 4.0). After converting everything works fine including crystal report (SAP Version). But whenever i open website source in visual studio 2010, then below error message occurred again and again.

**"We have detected that your solution was created using an older or unknown version of crystal Reports. You can convert it to Crystal reports for Visual Studio 2010. If you choose not to convert, some design-time features may not work properly"**

I already tried below points

1) Deleted existing older crystal reports Version=10.5.3700.0  from web.config file.

2) And also tried deleted older crystal report and try to create new crystal report in the project using visual studio 2010. After that same thing happen when i close visual studio 2010 and reopen that conversion error occur again.

If i create fresh report in new website(except this website source) in visual studio 2010, that's work perfectly no issue.

What is the reason for this issue? Please help me if anyone known about this error already.

Comment: Ravi, did you find any answer to this question? Did John's answer fix it?

Comment: Some related discussion here http://scn.sap.com/thread/2066105

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the Crystal Reports installer for Visual Studio 2010?

http://scn.sap.com/people/coy.yonce/blog/2010/11/12/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010-production-release-now-available